# How to mock ApexTestQueueItem, AsyncApexJob, and ApexTestResult for test coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm currently working on a set of classes that do the following:

A class that when instantiated and executed, queues all Test classes in Apex to run by inserting ApexTestQueueItems. I call this one HammerTest.

- A second class that can be scheduled to check on the tests by grabbing AsyncApexJobs with the same shared ParentJobId as the ApexTestQueueItems and seeing if they are in 'Aborted', 'Completed', or 'Failed'. If they are all done, it sends out an email with all info from ApexTestResult. If not it reschedules itself. I call this class HammerTestFollowUp.

I got both classes working as intended, except for test coverage on the second class. I'm running into issues because I can't figure out how to effectively mock ApexTestQueueItem, ApexAsyncJob, and ApexTestResult.

```
public class HammerTestFollowUp implements Schedulable {
    public Id jobId;
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> allTests = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :this.jobId];
        List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :this.jobId AND Status IN ('Aborted', 'Completed', 'Failed')];
        if (allTests.size() == finishedTests.size()) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = composeEmail(finishedTests);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> {mail});
            abortCron(ctx.getTriggerId());
        } else {
            abortCron(ctx.getTriggerId());
            HammerTest.scheduleFollowUp(this.jobId);
        }
    }
    private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage composeEmail(List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests) {
        String emailAddress = 'testemail@test.com';
        List<String> addresses = new List<String>();
        addresses.add(emailAddress);
        String subject ='Apex Hammer Test Results';
        String emailBody = createEmailBody(finishedTests);
        System.debug(emailBody);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setToAddresses(addresses);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(emailBody);
        return mail;
    }
        private String createEmailBody(List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests) {
        List<ApexTestResult> results = [SELECT MethodName, Outcome, StackTrace, Message FROM ApexTestResult WHERE AsyncApexJobId IN :finishedTests];
        String emailBody = '';
        for (ApexTestResult result : results) {
            String currentResult = result.MethodName + ': ' + result.Outcome;
            if (result.message != null) {
                currentResult += result.Message + '\n at ' + result.StackTrace;
            }
            currentResult += '\n';
            emailBody = emailBody + currentResult;
        }
        return emailBody;
    }
    private void abortCron (Id cron) {
        System.abortJob(cron);
    }
}
```

I searched around a bit, but it doesn't seem like a lot of people have tried using these in this way.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for this is to move the queries into a [Selector layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_selector_l_principles) and then use dependency injection to use a mock selector during testmethods rather than the PROD selector when running normally

Now I am a particular fan of the fflib pattern and ApexMocks (which exploits the StubApi) for doing all this but there are other approaches that accomplish the same Dependency Injection model with less code (but with fewer bells and whistles)

> Here's the fflib Selector for AsyncApexJob

```
public  class AsyncApexJobsSelector implements IAsyncApexJobsSelector {

    /**
        Force.com Enterprise Architecture Separation of Concerns Selector Layer: AsyncApexJob
        All selectors follow this pattern. Enables mocking through the Application.Selector.setMock

        Usage:
        AsyncApexJob[] logs = AsyncApexJobsSelector.newInstance().selectXXXX(args)

        See Force.com Enterprise Architecture 2nd Edition Chapter 7
    **/


    private static final Boolean INCLUDE_FIELDSETS  = false;    // false is default, if true, class must include getSobjectFieldList
    private static final Boolean ENFORCE_CRUD       = true;     // true is default
    private static final Boolean ENFORCE_FLS        = false;    // false is default
    private static final Boolean SORT_SELECT_FIELDS = true;     // true is default



    public override String getOrderBy() {return 'CreatedDate';}     // default field to order results by if not otherwise specified

    public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {    // keep in alpha order, whatever is listed here is unioned with fieldsets
        return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {
            AsyncApexJob.ApexClassID,   
            AsyncApexJob.CompletedDate, 
            AsyncApexJob.ExtendedStatus,    
            AsyncApexJob.JobItemsProcessed, 
            AsyncApexJob.JobType,   
            AsyncApexJob.NumberOfErrors,    
            AsyncApexJob.Status,    
            AsyncApexJob.TotalJobItems  
        };
    }



    public AsyncApexJobsSelector() {    
        super(INCLUDE_FIELDSETS,ENFORCE_CRUD,ENFORCE_FLS,SORT_SELECT_FIELDS);       
    }

    /**
    *   Factory to provide caller with a new Selector. Enables selectors to be mocked 
    **/ 
    public static IAsyncApexJobsSelector newInstance()    {
        return (IAsyncApexJobsSelector) Application.Selector.newInstance(AsyncApexJob.SObjectType);
    }

    /**
    *   getSObjectType : Used to construct queries. Required. 
    **/
    public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType() {return AsyncApexJob.SObjectType;}


/**
    *   selectById  : default selector, returns all matching SObjects for fields defined by getSObjectFieldList
    **/
    public virtual AsyncApexJob[] selectById(Set<Id> ids) {
        return ids.isEmpty() ? new List<AsyncApexJob> () : (AsyncApexJob[]) selectSObjectsById(ids);
    } 

    public virtual AsyncApexJob[] selectByIdAndStatus(Id jobId, Set<String> statuses) {
      flib_QueryFactory aajQF = newQueryFactory()
                                .selectFields(new List<String> {
                                    'ApexClass.Name'})
                                .setCondition( 'Id = :jobId AND ' +
                                               ' Status IN :statuses')
                                ;
    return Database.query(aajQF.toSOQL());
    }
    ... add more selector methods here ...   
}
```

> You need an interface that both the prod and mock selector will implement

```
public interface IAsyncApexJobsSelector {

    /**
        fflib Enterprise Architecture interface for Selector. Enables construction of mock selectors for unit testing
        As methods are added to the Selector, add to the interface
    **/

    AsyncApexJob[] selectById(set<ID> ids);
    AsyncApexJob[] selectByIdAnbdStatus(Id id, Set<String> statuses);
}
```

> Which you will invoke in your class/method

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> allTests =
          AsyncApexJobsSelector.newInstance().selectbyId(new Set<id> {jobid});
        List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests = 
          AsyncApexJobsSelector.newInstance().selectbyIdAndStatus(jobid,
                 new Set<String> { 'Aborted', 'Completed', 'Failed'});
```

> fflib requires an Application.cls (factories and mock injection) and here's an excerpt ...

```
public class Application {

    /**
    * SELECTOR LAYER FACTORIES; add new ones for new sobjects
    **/

    public static final fflib_Application.SelectorFactory Selector =
        new fflib_Application.SelectorFactory(
            new Map<SObjectType, Type> {
                    Account.SObjectType                         => AccountsSelector.class,
                    Asset.SObjectType                           => AssetsSelector.class,
                    AsyncApexJob.SObjectType                    => AsyncApexJobsSelector.class
    }
}
```

> and the testmethod

```
@isTest
private static void myTestMethod() {
  // given mocking framework
  fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

  // given mock selector results
  AsyncApexJob[] mockAsyncApexJobs0 = (AsyncApexJob[])
     JSON.deserialize('[{"CompletedDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z", ...}]',
             List<AsyncApexJob>.class); 
  AsyncApexJob[] mockAsyncApexJobs0 = (AsyncApexJob[])
     JSON.deserialize('[' +
         '"CompletedDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z", ...},' +
         '"CompletedDate": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z", ...}' +
         ']',
             List<AsyncApexJob>.class); 

  // Given mock selector(s)
AsyncApexJobsSelector mockAsyncApexJobsSelector = (AsyncApexJobsSelector) mocks.mock(AsyncApexJobsSelector.class);
mocks.startStubbing();
mocks.when(mockAsyncApexJobsSelector.SObjectType()).thenReturn(AsyncApexJob.SObjectType);
mocks.when(mockAsyncApexJobsSelector.selectById(fflib_Match.anyId()))
        .thenReturn(mockAsyncApexJobs0);
mocks.when(mockAsyncApexJobsSelector.selectByIdAndStatuses(
            fflib_Match.anyId(),(Set<String>)fflib_Match.anyObject())
        .thenReturn(mockAsyncApexJobs1);
mocks.stopStubbing();
// Given mocks injected
Application.Selector.setMock(mockAsyncApexJobsSelector);

// When code is invoked
new HammerTestFollup.execute(null);

// Then verify 
...asserts or apexmocks verifies go here
}
```

> Summarized

- You change your prod code to call a method in a class that is instantiated by a factory.
- The prod code, when it calls the factory returns a selector object that does real SOQL;
- in testing, you inject a mock selector object that returns mocked sobjects.
- The mocked sobjects are constructed using Json.deserialize as they can't otherwise be constructed for `AsyncApexJob`
- You can read about [ApexMocks (gitHub)](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) or, if you don't find this to your taste, google "apex dependency injection". Editorial note: ApexMocks is super powerful at helping you with unit tests and can make your whole test suite run faster as you don't have to do DML to construct test data. Applications that do a good job of [separation of concerns](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl) and [also Service Layer here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl) benefit the most from apexmocks.

> Other ApexMocks references not listed in the GitHub

- [ApexMocks and Enterprise Patterns](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/11/apex-mocks-and-enterprise-patterns-first-in-a-series/)
- [ApexMocks and SFDX, also illustrates a DI alternative](https://github.com/frup42/apex-mocks-sfdx)

Comment: +1. I started reading Apex Enterprise Pattern by Andy, it's genuinely quite good.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  yes, when I read the first edition (2nd edition is better as it addresses unit testing w apexmocks; 3rd is on the way), it was 'revelatory' compared to what I had done in the past.

Comment: I started to read that too - just never enough time! While the fflib stuff is quite powerful and drives very much pattern-based coding it clearly takes quite a bit of boilerplate to get it going which is what puts me off. We have our own far simpler pattern somewhat based on the idea of dependency injection which works for us. Still, a worthy response so +1 from me as well...

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware of two approaches that allow you to mock system objects like these that (depending on the system objects involved) can be used individually or together:

1. Provide a "Plain Old Apex Object" with equivalent properties to the system object and isolate the actual access to the real system objects in a small accessor object exposing the "POAO" analogues of the system objects and ensure you have a way to switch out the accessor used for a mock version. You can always take this approach.
2. Leverage JSON deserialization to allow creation of mock instances of system objects directly. You may find that some system objects don't allow such instantiation.

I find that AsyncApexJob allows the deserialization dodge. Try this out in anon apex for example:

```
String value = JSON.serialize([SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob LIMIT 1][0]);
AsyncApexJob job = (AsyncApexJob) JSON.deserialize(value, AsyncApexJob.class);
System.debug(job);
```

You can see whether this is possible with the other objects for yourself.

Where deserialization is supported all you have to do is isolate the actual data access into a simple, usually single-line, protected virtual method, for example:

```
public virtual class HammerTestFollowUp implements Schedulable {
    public Id jobId;

    protected virtual List<AsyncApexJob> getAllTests(Id jobId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :jobId];
    }

    protected virtual List<AsyncApexJob> getFinishedTests(Id jobId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :jobId AND Status IN ('Aborted', 'Completed', 'Failed')];
    }

    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> allTests = getAllTests(this.jobId);
        List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests = getFinishedTests(this.jobId);
        if (allTests.size() == finishedTests.size()) {
```

What you then do in your tests is extend this target class and override the data access methods - yes, this means some code is not covered which is why you keep these accessor methods to one line if at all possible. The test implementations might look something like:

```
private class HammerTestFollowUpTest {
    private static final String RUNNING_APEX_JOBS = '[{"attributes":{"type":"AsyncApexJob","url":"/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/AsyncApexJob/7072D00000NS7WqQAL"},"Id":"7072D00000NS7WqQAL","Status":"Queued"}]';
    private static final String FINISHED_APEX_JOBS = ...;

    private class TestHammerTestFollowUp extends HammerTestFollowUp {
        protected override virtual List<AsyncApexJob> getAllTests(Id jobId) {
            return (List<AsyncApexJob>) JSON.deserialize(RUNNING_APEX_JOBS, List<AsyncApexJob>.class);
        }

        ...
```

Those test methods would instantiate the TestHammerTestFollowUp class and run tests against this instead of the real thing. Most of the production code is then tested (except for the real data access).

You can take similar approaches, perhaps structured a bit differently. E.g. you can pull all the accessor methods out of the code and into a separate virtual class that you separately instantiate and substitute alternatives for via TestVisible access to a private member in the target class:

```
public virtual class AsyncApexJobAccessor {
    public virtual List<AsyncApexJob> query(String query) {
        return (List<AsyncApexJob>) Database.query(query);
    }
}

public class HammerTestFollowUpTest {
    @TestVisible
    private static AsyncApexJobAccessor ACCESSOR = new AsyncApexJobAccessor();

    public Id jobId;
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> allTests = ACCESSOR.query('SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = \'' + this.jobId + '\'');
        List<AsyncApexJob> ...
```

Again, your test has a mock using JSON.deserialize as required, but now it just slots the required instance in by assigning to the test visible private static ACCESSOR before calling the production code.

You can probably work out the "POAO" variant for yourself, using this where you have to (or if you dislike the JSON approach).

Comment: +1. If I am not wrong its called POTATO(https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1100481781537468417?s=20)

Comment: OP certainly got the gamut of possible responses from you-Pranay-me !

Comment: @PranayJaiswal: yes, what a smash-ing name. I'll bake that into my code and let the chips process it. No roasts needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not mock `finishedTests` using [@TestVisble](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) annotation

```
public class HammerTestFollowUp implements Schedulable {
    public Id jobId;

    @TestVisible
    private List<AsyncApexJob> finishedTests;

    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> allTests = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :this.jobId];

        if(finishedTests==null){
            finishedTests = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :this.jobId AND Status IN ('Aborted', 'Completed', 'Failed')];

        }
        if (allTests.size() == finishedTests.size()) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = composeEmail(finishedTests);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> {mail});
            abortCron(ctx.getTriggerId());
        } else {
            abortCron(ctx.getTriggerId());
            HammerTest.scheduleFollowUp(this.jobId);
        }
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private static void testSchduler(){

    HammerTestFollowUp  hw = new HammerTestFollowUp ();
    hw.finishedTests  = (List<AsyncApexJob>)JSON.deserialize('[{"attributes":{"type":"AsyncApexJob","url":"/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/AsyncApexJob/7070C000004CgOrQAK"},"Id":"7070C000004CgOrQAK","Status":"Completed"},{"attributes":{"type":"AsyncApexJob","url":"/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/AsyncApexJob/7070C000004CgRmQAK"},"Id":"7070C000004CgRmQAK","Status":"Completed"}]' , ist<AsyncApexJob>.class);
    Test.startTest();
    String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? *';
    System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest',  CRON_EXP, hw);            
    Test.stopTest();
    //Assert here
}
```